# Does it make sense to make this aggregate roots design?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

Let's assume a project presenting those specifications:

- Each `Employee` can organize a `Meeting` inviting other `Employee`s.
- Each `Employee` can accept the invitation to participate to the `Meeting`, while the number of max `Participation`s isn't exceeded.
- Any `Manager` of the `Employee` creator can cancel the `Meeting` at any time.

IMO, the invariants are:

- A Meeting `exists` as long as the creator (`Employee`) exists (not deleted or flag as deleted).
- There shouldn't be at any time a `Meeting` containing a number of participants superior to the limite intended.
- Any `Employee` that cancels its created `Meeting` should have also this `Participation`s canceled /deleted.
- When a `Manager` cancels an `Employee`'s `Meeting`, both the `Meeting` and the `Participation`s should be deleted.

Should I make:

- the `Employee` an Aggregate Root, containing the collection of its created `Meeting`s.
- `Meeting` being thus an inner entity of `Employee` and containing a collection of `Participation`s.
- Manager as the other Aggregate Root, containing a collection of its `Employee`s.

Thus there would be just to Aggregate Roots:
`Employee` and `Manager`.
Indeed, a Manager could be fired and then is not part of an invariant with the `Employee`, and vice versa.

In details:
_ `Employee` would provide a method `createParticipation`, encapsulating checks for the important rules like whether the number max of participants is exceeded.
_ `Employee` would provide also a Factory to create `Meeting`, allowing to always assign the correct `EmployeeId` to the `Meeting`.
_ Only two repositories would be created: `EmployeeRepository` and `ManagerRepository`, avoiding direct access to respective inner parts.
(that deals only with creations, deletions would be similar)

Therefore, in order to create a `Meeting`'s `Participation`, my entry point would be the creator(`Employee`) that I retrieve through the `EmployeeRepository`.

Does it make sense in order to follow strict DDD practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Employee aggregate is way too big. This creates concurrency issues. What would happen if two employees accept the invitation in the same time? One transaction would be rolled back because they try to modify the same aggregate. Unless you designed some fancy conflict resolution logic.

Instead, consider Participation and Meeting to be separate aggregates.

Comment: Indeed, I agree. Currently, that is what I have: Participation and Meeting being Aggregate Roots, as you promote. However, what about the invariant: "if an Employee is deleted, all its created meetings + participations concerning it should also be destroyed". How to handle that atomically? Should I go with eventual consistency in this case?

Comment: I see no benefit of transactional consistency here. Meetings are planned hours, days even weeks before. No one would ever notice any difference.

Comment: Ok, but besides, how to handle the specification: "does not exceed the number max of participants" if `Meeting` and `Participation` are both Aggregate Roots? I was reading the Evan's blue book, and in his example of "purchase order" (dealing with an unexpected number of OrderLineItems), he resolves the problem by gathering `Order` and `OrderLineItems` in one Aggregate Root whose entry point is `Order`. My use case is similar, isn't it?

Comment: Meeting should have a list of value objects referencing participation (ParticipationId). This article might help: http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/

Comment: :) I have already read the Vernon's book, I enjoyed it. So using references by Id (since `Participation` is another Aggregate, from the `Meeting` perspective), I would validate the participation through the number of participationIds, and let or not the participation be applied. If two `Employee`'s participate at the same time, I guess that the validation barrier might be bypassed because of concurrency issues. Therefore, should I lock the database anywhere (on the whole `Meeting` table (or node, if using a graph database)), while the transaction occurs? (thanks a lot for your answers :))

Comment: Do you mean that you want to invite more participants than you allow to enter?

Comment: Actually, it's like events, I send invitations but to more people than needed. (in order to be sure to have the required number of people) Interested people just declare their participation. Therefore, it could easily exceed the number max of persons I would allow for this event. I would like to have a mechanism to check for the limit, and I thought about locking the Meeting itself at each attempt of participation.

Comment: Of course, it would be `Meeting` that would do the check of the number limit to allow the participation to occur or not.

Comment: I would make Meeting and Participant part of the same Aggregate Root in order to keep the invariant.

Comment: Yes, in this case putting Participantion in the Meeting aggregate has more sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advices :) I made Participation a simple value object referencing the UserId of User's entity (so that I can link the whole for the graph database). Meeting having a collection of Participations